# Clion is not recognizing .py files as python files when I added a CMakeLists for one cc file

Tags: python, clion

CLion was working fine with my python files. Then I added one .cc and created a CMakeLists.txt for it, now when I tab to a python file all the imports and built-in functions like `open` or `int` are counted as errors.

I've looked into Settings -> Editor -> File Types and everything looks okay.

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you somehow remove the python module?

Comment: I fixed it! The problem was the cmakelists was in a subdirectory, when I moved it to the root folder the .py files are treated as expected

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the cmakelists was in a subdirectory, when I moved it to the root folder the .py files are treated as expected